# Connection to Database failed. Tomcat Apache

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache, tomcat

I'm currently experiencing issues with my local database, which i try to connect to using Apache Tomcat 7.0.

My configuration file is an exact copy of another run that I know for sure works, as I can see everything gets accepted, the only other "edit" is that I'm using a new Server (Same DB, simply copied).

I get the following exception in the System.log:

```
20 jun 2016 08:08:55 -- INFO -- Starting TMCare server on: Apache Tomcat/7.0.25.
20 jun 2016 08:08:55 -- INFO -- - Application properties...
20 jun 2016 08:08:55 -- INFO -- - Commands...
20 jun 2016 08:08:57 -- INFO -- - Session manager...
20 jun 2016 08:08:57 -- INFO -- - Data access (JDBC)...
20 jun 2016 08:08:58 -- INFO -- Database Isolation level set to '2'
20 jun 2016 08:08:58 -- ERROR -- Connecting to DAO failed.
20 jun 2016 08:08:58 -- INFO -- Waiting for DAO timeout (5 secs)...
20 jun 2016 08:09:03 -- INFO -- Database Isolation level set to '2'
20 jun 2016 08:09:03 -- FATAL -- error in init
dk.tmnet.tmt.dao.exceptions.DAOConnectionException: Kunne ikke få forbindelse til jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/Tmsund_prod.   // This is where my issue is. "Kunne ikke få forbindelse til ... " Simply translates into "Cannot connect to".
        at dk.tmnet.tmt.db.jdbc.JdbcConnectionPool.<init>(JdbcConnectionPool.java:104)
        at dk.tmnet.tmt.db.jdbc.JdbcDAOFactory.initialize(JdbcDAOFactory.java:1813)
        at dk.tmnet.tmt.config.Configurator.getDAOFactory(Configurator.java:784)
        at dk.tmnet.tmt.config.Configurator.initDAO(Configurator.java:837)
        at dk.tmnet.tmt.config.Configurator.init(Configurator.java:694)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:897)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:873)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1095)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1617)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My issue is at the bottom, but I thought I'd give you the whole startup sequence.

I have tried the following:
Ensured that the password and user is correct: Check, works.
Tried to connect from a management studio: Check, works.
Tried to connect from ANOTHER machine using management studio: Check, DOESN'T work.
Tried to turn off firewall from my local PC: Check, everything is off.

The above is tried and I simply cannot see a solution, yet I have no idea why it refuses connections.
I have tried setting the ports manually in management studio, that doesn't change the outcome either.

The DB and tomcat is installed on the same PC.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you paste the exception right here? There's a formatting option in the editor to make it readable and this way the question here would be self-contained and we'd not have to click on third party links. And, by the way, pasteguru currently returns "503 Service Unavailable" to me.

Comment: Is this what you meant, Olaf?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the driver installed in your non-working tomcat. It seems like your `dk.tmnet` component detects a problem (e.g. catches an exception, like "driver not found" and rethrows it without proper information). It might also be that there's a "root cause" following this exception that would tell you more about the circumstances.

I'm not using sqlserver, but vaguely remember that some time ago it required multiple jars. This might be ancient information...

Typically database driver jars go into tomcat's global lib directory (`tomcat/lib/`)